# How to get multi-line Text value - JQuery

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, javascript, jquery, list-form

How to **get** and **set** get multi-line Text value using jquery. I have tried following code to get my **Description** field value. But it's not working.

```
$("input[Title='Description Required Field']").val()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain Text Multiple field:

Get

```
$("textarea[title='Description']").val();
```

Set

```
$("textarea[title='Description']").val("test");
```

Answer (score 1):

Get multi-line Text field value :

```
$("textarea[id^='Description']")[0].innerHTML;
```

Set multi-line Text field value :

```
$("textarea[id^='Description']")[0].innerHTML = "Your text";
```

I hope this helps !!!